# How to add author nickname to wordpress post permalink urls?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How to add author nickname to post permalink urls?

Like: `http://example.com/post-title-%nickname%`

Comment: You could always edit the slug, while on the post...The option is enabled by default, right below the title.

Comment: I know, but nickname must be added automatically